# Contact to a lead in CRM Dynamics 2013

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I know in `CRM 2011` you can not `convert a contact to lead`. Is it possible in `CRM 2013` .

In simple words i have created a contact and grouped it in to a account. I would like to convert this contact in to lead so that i can make a sales entry.

Strange all leading CRM package provides this , in 2011 its not available is it there in 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is not available out of the box. However, there are a number of ways to implement this.

The easiest would be to create an 'On Demand' Workflow - that creates a Lead with information from the Contact. This can be run manually against specific Contacts - as I presume you don't want to do this for every Contact.

The alternative is to use the SDK, you could create a Lead from the information in the Contact and have a Ribbon button to invoke the SDK code.

Typically, you would convert (Qualify) a Lead into to an Account, Contact and/or Opportunity. It is unusual to convert a Contact to a Lead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is one of terminology, not functionality.

If you want to record a new potential sale for an existing Account or Contact, the most obvious thing to do would be to create an Opportunity.

If for some reason you want to create a potential potential deal, and want to use a Lead to hold this so you can do a more formal pre-qualification before you get to Opportunity, then just create a Lead linked to the Contact and Account. Since there is a relationship there already, you cold do this by adding a sub-grid on the Contact form, or adding Leads to the navigation on the form (like any other child entity).

You don't need to "convert" the Contact, keep that as it is and just add another record to represent the possible new sale.